# Lebesgue integral and iterated integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am learning lebesgue integral at the moment, and come across a question in homework, but find it really confused. The question states:

[image]

I first tried to compute the iterated integral by Riemann integral, and find that the iterated integral is infinite no matter which order I used. So I think probably here the result of Lebesgue integral is different. But how to compute the iterated integral using Lebesgue integral? The domain are split equally into 2 squares in the unit box if using Riemann integral. Do we still have this in Lebesgue integral? Maybe some sequence of simple functions is needed, but I am not sure how to construct that in an iterated case.

I think the double integral does not exist as the 2 functions are not measurable, and if we compute the integral we will probably find the 2 iterated integral different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at the iterated integral

$$I := \iint f(x,y) \, \lambda(dx) \, \lambda(dy).$$

(Here $\lambda$ denotes the (one-dimensional) Lebesgue measure.) Since $f(x,y)=0$ whenever $|x| \geq 1$ or $|y| \geq 1$, we have

$$I = \int_{(0,1)} \int_{(0,1)} f(x,y) \, \lambda(dx) \, \lambda(dy). \tag{1}$$

Now fix $y \in (0,1)$. By the very definition of $f$, we have

$$\begin{align*} \int_{(0,1)} f(x,y) \, \lambda(dx) &= \int_{(0,y)} \frac{1}{y^2} \, \lambda(dx) - \int_{(y,1)} \frac{1}{x^2} \, \lambda(dx) \\ &= \frac{1}{y^2} \cdot y - \int_{(y,1)} \frac{1}{x^2} \, \lambda(dx). \end{align*}$$

In order to calculate the second integral, we note that he mapping $[y,1] \ni x \mapsto \frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous (as $y>0$!) and therefore Riemann-integrable. It is well-known that this implies that Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral coincide. Consequently, we obtain

$$\int_{(0,1)} f(x,y) \, \lambda(dx) = \frac{1}{y} + \left[\frac{1}{x} \right]_{y}^1 = 1.$$

Plugging this into $(1)$, we find $I=1$. A very similar argumentation shows that

$$J := \int_{(0,1)} \int_{(0,1)} f(x,y) \, \lambda(dy) \, \lambda(dx) = -1.$$

Since the iterated integrals $I$ and $J$ do not coincide, this already implies (by Fubini's theorem) that the double integral does not exist. (Note that this has nothing to do with measurability; the function $f$ is perfectly well measurable.)

Comment: But Fubini's Theorm states measurable functions should have the same iterated integrals, which are the same as the double integral. But why do we have such a result with f being measurable?

Comment: @naga No, that's not what Fubini's theorem states. It states that *if* the double integral exists, then the iterated integrals are the same.

Comment: So here f is measurable, but not integrable, which makes the 2 iterated integral different?

Comment: @naga Yes, that's it.